# How to keep the active tab while navigating to another view?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, cordova, ionic2, angular-ui-router

I'm working on a Cordova/Ionic 2/AngularJS project and I'm facing the following issue. I have defined 5 main navigation tabs with the corresponding views, but I have one view (this one contains an iFrame), which I want to navigate to from any of my main tabs, the problem is I need to keep the active tab selected

My tabs definition look like this:

```
<ion-tabs ng-controller="BaseTabs as ctrl"
          class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive"
          delegate-handle="tabs">

  <ion-tab title="Featured" icon="featured" ng-click="ctrl.openCatalog()"
           ui-sref="tab.app-catalog.featured" on-select="ctrl.update()">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app-home"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Catalog" icon="shop" ng-click="ctrl.openCatalogSearch()" 
           ui-sref="tab.app-catalog-search" on-select="ctrl.update()">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app-catalog-search"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

...

  <ion-tab title="More" icon="more" ng-click="ctrl.openMore()"
           ui-sref="tab.app-more-content" on-select="ctrl.update()">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-app-user"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

in my iframe controller I have the following:

```
    $stateProvider.state(
      'tab.app-base-frame', {
        url    : '/base/frame:url',
        parent : 'tab',
        views  : {
          'tab-app-home' : {
            templateUrl  : 'templates/app/base/frame.html',
            controller   : 'BaseFrame',
            controllerAs : 'ctrl'
          }
        },
        params : {
          url   : ''
          title : false
        }
      }
    )
```

Since in the controller I have the views set *tab-app-home*, each time I open the iframe view I get the home tab selected instead of the one active before invoking the iframe.

So here is my question, is there a way to dynamically set the view based on parameters? Or maybe a more practical solution rather than the way I have done so far?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
import {Tabs} from “ionic-angular”;

@Page({
    template: <ion-tabs #paymentTabs [tabbarLayout]="tabBarLayout" 
    [selectedIndex]="tabsIndex" preloadTabs="false"> <ion-tab tabIcon="list-box" 
    tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab> <ion-tab tabIcon="list-box" 
    tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab> </ion-tabs>,
})
export class PaymentTab {
    @ViewChild(“paymentTabs”) paymentTabs: Tabs;

    constructor() {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(“this.paymentTabs”);
            this.paymentTabs.select(1);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```